# Add a shortcode to woocommerce emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use a free plugin to provide estimated delivery date for orders , the plugin have its shortcode to show the estimated time [display_ship_est], i need to output this shortcode to the default woocommerce notification emails . any help please , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use a hook like `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` for exemple

```
add_action( "woocommerce_email_after_order_table", "custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table", 10, 1);

function custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table( $order ) {

    echo 'Estimated delivery date is'. wse_shipping_est('', '', 0);
    // or
    echo do_shortcode( '[display_ship_est]' );

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help , isn't there a hook to display it directly with the shipping field , with the shipping method label ?

Comment: Choose your hook
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/

Comment: i think i'm in wrong path , i need to find how to add a shortcode to the shipping label itself